# Creating Forms with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get my form working since two days.
I'm reading the chapter "Forms" in the Symfony book up and down but i don't know what I'm doing wrong.
This is my Entity class:

```
/**
 * Homecontent
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="homecontent", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_idx", columns={"author_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Homecontent
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="home_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $homeId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="text", nullable=false)
     *
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="picture_path", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $picturePath;

    /**
     * @var \Contentuser
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contentuser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="content_user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $author;
```

This is my controller:

```
/**
     * @param $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/content/insert")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $content = new HomecontentType();
        $form = $this->createForm(HomecontentType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager();
            $em->persist($content);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('worked check index');
        }
        return $this->render('Form/ContentForm.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

And this is my Form Class:

```
/**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('content')
            ->add('picturePath')
            ->add('date',DateTimeType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Homecontent'
        ));
    }
}
```

I use twig for the rendering and it's working, but when i want to submit it i get an error

> The class 'AppBundle\Form\HomecontentType' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\Entity

I'm sorry for the long code section.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the `indexAction` you have error, the correct code is:

```
$content = new Homecontent();
$form = $this->createForm(HomecontentType::class, $content);
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer now I'm getting a new error:

The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Homecontent, but is an instance of class AppBundle\Form\HomecontentType. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class AppBundle\Form\HomecontentType to an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Homecontent.

Comment: did you change both lines ?, you had 2 errors in first 2 lines

Comment: Now its working, I cleared the Symfony Cache...
Thank you very much!
Do you have any tipps for me, how to handle the relation in the forms to do a dropdown with the author name?

Comment: Use entity form field type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html